# I want to write a for loop adding a new key to a dictionary with one condition, number of purchases have to be >=3

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, for-loop, conditional-statements

```
customers = {

'customer 1':{'name': 'John Smith', 'city': 'New York', 'nr_or_purchases': 3, 'items':['coffee', 'cookies', 'milk']},

'customer 2':{'name': 'Rebeca Collins', 'city': 'New York', 'nr_or_purchases': 1, 'items':['sugar']},

'customer 3':{'name': 'Edward Matthews', 'city': 'Boston', 'nr_or_purchases': 4, 'items':['bananas', 'apples', 'oranges', 'cherries' ]},

'customer 4':{'name': 'Maria Simmons', 'city': 'Boston', 'nr_or_purchases': 3, 'items':['ham', 'cheese', 'butter']}}
```

I want to write a for loop to add to every customer with more than 3 purchases a new key called 'promo' : 'coupon'

Answer (score 0):

```
for customer in customers: # loop through your customers dictionary
    if customers[customer]["nr_or_purchases"] > 3: # check the item for a condition
        customers[customer]["promo"] = "coupon" # if the condition applies, do something
```

Also, if your dictionary's primary label is going to be something like 'customer 1', 'customer 2', etc (i.e. ordered elements) you should be using an array of dictionaries instead of a dictionary of dictionaries.